# How to get objectAtIndex in my method?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I get `objectAtIndex` in my Method.

For example if I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

i can get it with

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [currentCourses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

how can i do the same in other method like this?

```
-(void)longPress : (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)rec {
if (rec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
 //   NSIndexPath *myPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    /*NSArray *currentCourses = [self currentCourses:myIP0.section];
    billContent *bc = [currentCourses objectAtIndex:myIP0.section];
    NSLog(@"title - %@", bc.billTitle);*/
  //  NSLog(@"%@", myPath.row);

  //NSLog(@"did selected - %d", indexPath.row);

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)longPress : (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)rec {
CGPoint swipeLocation = [rec locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
UITableViewCell *swipedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
}
```